# Cache an IFormFile in singleton, "cannot access a closed stream" .NET Core & C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am creating a very simple order model program in .NET Core.

When an order is placed, I want to save the order in a singleton class `OrderService`.

Here is that class:

```
public class OrderService
{
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();

    public OrderService() { }

    public void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        Orders.Add(order);
    }

    public Order GetOrder(string id)
    {
        var order = Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
        return order ?? throw new Exception("Order not found");
    }
}
```

The order has an `IFormFile` property. And when I fetch the order from the singleton and try to `OpenReadStream()`, I get an exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
> ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name'

Here is exactly where it crashes (I try to read the file content to append it as an email attachment):

```
if (order.Watch.DialDesignFile != null)
{
    var attachment = new MimePart(order.Watch.DialDesignFile.ContentType)
            {
                Content = new MimeContent(order.Watch.DialDesignFile.OpenReadStream()),
                ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.Attachment),
                ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                FileName = order.Watch.DialDesignFile.FileName
            };

    bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards Max

Comment: You should process the IFormFile in the Action method where it originates, instead of doing it later. It seems very likely that .NET disposes it right after it has called your Action method.

Comment: I found the problem! I did everything async and therefore .NET disposed them before I could handle them, made everything synchr.. and everything works! Thanks!